# OpenOffice Calc Compare 2 cols and print col if true

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have two cols in Calc and want to compare both and print in col if it's a duplicate. Example:

```
A    B    C
1    2    
2    2    2
3    3    3
4    5    
5    6    
6    7    
7    7    7
8    8    8
9    9    9
```

What is the formula I need to print in col c to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to use in column C, to test if columns A and B are equals

```
=IF(A1=B1;B1;"")
```

Comment: That prints a "0" instead of printing the duplicated value.

Comment: %$#@ !@#$ ^%$# &^%^ *&!@ <-That's a lot of cursing if you didn't notice. I had that formula you posted already before I came here and it was printing a 0. But I had my cells printed in cols in like j and k instead of a and b. For some reason I just was not paying attention. So freaking mad right now. Thanks for the help.